# css height different between pages

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use `md-card` in a page in my application. I also have an `md-autocomplete` in my home page. I had to alter the `angular-material.css` in order to make the autocomplete display perfectly in my home page.

But in my product page where I use `md-card`, it does not appear properly.

This is the css that makes the product page appear incorrect :

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;  ----> This makes the page incorrect.
    position: relative
}
```

Removing the height makes the other pages incorrect but the product page correct. Hence I need the `height` attribute in my other pages to display them correctly.

The below is the md-card code:

```
<div class="container ">
  <!-- <div style="margin-top: 5%" flex-sm flex-gt-sm="100" ng-repeat="review in reviews"> -->
  <div style="margin-top: 5%" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    <md-card ng-repeat="review in reviews" md-theme="dark-grey" md-theme-watch>
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-headline">Too Good</span>
          <span class="md-subhead">username</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
        <md-card-title-media>
          <div class="md-media-sm card-media">
            <img ng-src="{{review
    .imgurl}}" alt="">
          </div>
        </md-card-title-media>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content class="col-md-11">
        <hm-read-more hm-text="{{text}}" hm-limit="100" hm-more-text="read more" hm-less-text="read less" hm-dots-class="dots" hm-link-class="links">
        </hm-read-more>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Like</md-button>
        <md-button>Dislike</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

My application url : [Home page](http://treppr.herokuapp.com/#/home)

The product page : [Product page](http://treppr.herokuapp.com/#/product/s)

Please help me fix this css issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give background colour to html or remove the `height: 100%;` for body. Specifying `min-height` not necessary.

```
html {
    background: #A6333D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

This will do the trick :)

Comment: This made the product page right. But the other pages got messed up.

Comment: When you just add the min-height: 100vh to your page, the style gets overridden. Use !important instead like in the updated answer.